# How to POST data into a datatable

Tags: php, database, post

The following text will show you my code, seperatet in different files.

**datensenden.php**:

```
    echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td><h6>Bitte Datei ausw&auml;hlen:</h6></td>\n";
        echo "<div><td><INPUT NAME=\"userfiles[]\" TYPE=\"file\" multiple='multiple'></td>\n ";
        If (isset($_POST['f']['fdateiname'])){
    echo 'value="' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["f"]["fdateiname"]).  '"/></div>';
}
        echo "</tr>\n";
```

**datensenden_copy.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../../require.php");

$num_rows  =  mysql_num_rows($result);
 $omy= new clsMYSQL();
$output = '';
if  ($num_rows)  {
$fmandantnr=$_POST['mandantnr'];
$fdatum=$_POST['datum'];
$fdateiname=$_POST['dateiname'];

$query = "SELECT iksql INSERT  INTO  email_hochladen (fmandantnr,  fdatum,  fdateiname)VALUES('$fmandantnr',  '$fdatum','$fdateiname')";
$omy->Query($query);
}
?>
```

What I've tried to do here is to get from the upload of a file in "datensenden.php" the name and write it into a database table.

So like someone uploaded "*test.rar*" and now this should be in my database table "*email_hochladen*" under "*fdateiname*"

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Remove `SELECT iksql`

Comment: Still doesn't show up in the datatable.. really strange

Comment: Does somebody know a solution ? I'm still looking in stackoverflow but can't find anything similair

Comment: Why do you have you POST variables in IF statement of some kind sql?

Comment: B001 talked about `SELECT iksql INSERT INTO` part, i'm talking about `if  ($num_rows)  {` and 3 lines above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug your code again:

```
if  ($num_rows)
```

Try:

```
if  ($num_rows>0)
```

Remove SELECT iksql :

```
$query = "SELECT iksql INSERT  INTO  email_hochladen (fmandantnr,  fdatum,  fdateiname)VALUES('$fmandantnr',  '$fdatum','$fdateiname')";
```

Try removing whitespaces:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO email_hochladen (fmandantnr,fdatum,fdateiname) VALUES ('$fmandantnr','$fdatum','$fdateiname')";
```

If you want to send a form with files, try doing a clean form first:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select files: <input type="file" name="userfiles" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then convert it to php code.
It's an advice.